# Add Language of Source to Natbib Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, languages, bibliographystyle

As I am using the Natbib package but it does not display the language of the source. I put the language for all non-English entries like the example below. How can I make sure it displays the language like "*German"* in de bibliography? There is the same problem for other languages like French. Therefore I cannot change the language of the whole document since that is in English and the majority of the sources too.

Thanks in advance!
[image: Snapshot of the current bibliography]

```
@article{reichardt1975onsy,
    title = {{Definition Und Messgrundlage Eines Objektiven Masses Zur Ermittlung Der Grenze Zwischen Brauchbarer Und Unbrauchbarer Durchsichtigkeit Bei Musikdarbietung.}},
    year = {1975},
    journal = {Acustica},
    author = {Reichardt, W. and Abdel Alim, O. and Schmidt, W.},
    number = {3},
    pages = {126--137},
    volume = {32},
    language = {German}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. This is related to your bib style. Some bib styles will not show the `language` field. Please provide more contexts, and desirably a minimum working example (MWE).

Comment: Where would you even want the "language" field to show? You cite a source, with Author, Title, Journal/Book Title etc.: would you want "German" added to that? Or do you want to use per-language bibliographies, i.e. group all the English/French/German books together?

Comment: Usually `language` is used by some styles, e.g., the styles of [package `babelbib`](https://www.can.org/pkg/babelbib) not to print the language, but to switch to the language for a correct output (e.g., using “Herausgeber” instead of “editor” and the hyphenation of that language). So maybe using `language` to print the name of the language is not ideally (or only, if the common meaning should also be used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using the Natbib package but it does not display the language of the source

The `natbib` package does *not* govern whether or not a field called `language` is processed. That's the job of the bibliography style that's in use.

Unfortunately, very few BibTeX-based bibliography styles are programmed to recognize and process a field called `language`. In contrast, just about all BibTeX-based bibliography styles are programmed to process the `note` field -- for almost all entry types.

Question: Are you willing and able to change `language = {German}` to, say, `note = {Language: German}` in the bib file?